# How to replace Anko's doAsync, uiThread with kotlin 1.1.0 kotlinx-coroutines-core lib's features?

Tags: android, kotlin

i have some code like:

```
doAsync{
...
uiThread{
...
}
}
```

how can i replace doAsync and uiThread with something new from kotlinx-coroutines-core lib?

Answer (score 12):

**Update for coroutines library version 0.26:**

`UI` has been renamed to `Main`. Complete working example for 0.26:

```
async(CommonPool) {
    ...
    withContext(Main) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You don't need to read further from here, I'm leaving it up for people interested in the evolution of this solution.

---

**Update for coroutines library version 0.20:**

`run` is now deprecated, you should use `withContext` instead. Complete working example for 0.20:

```
async(CommonPool) {
    ...
    withContext(UI) {
        ...
    }
}
```

---

**Update since the coroutines library was updated to version 0.13:**

You can now add a dependency on `compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:0.13'` to your gradle to import the android-specific `UI` coroutine context and use it like this:

```
async(CommonPool) {
    ...
    run(UI) {
        ...
    }
}
```

No need to define your own coroutine dispatcher anymore, as was still needed at the time of the original answer below.

---

**Original answer:**

It should work like this:

```
async(CommonPool) {
    ...
    run(MainThread) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that right now, there is no standard implementation of `MainThread` that takes you back to the main thread on Android (this will come in a future release though!), so you would have to do that yourself, for example like this:

```
val MainThread = object : Executor {
    private val mHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

    override fun execute(command: Runnable) {
        mHandler.post(command)
    }
}.toCoroutineDispatcher()
```

Comment: Just a note:
 `run(UI) { ... }`
is now deprecated and 
`withContext(UI) {...}`
should be used instead.

Comment: @PepaNovotný Good catch! Which version of anko did this happen in?

Comment: It was deprecated in 0.20 as requested in https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/134

Comment: @PepaNovotný Great, thanks for the info! I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 11):

The exact replacement for the pseudocode in the question is

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {  // replaces doAsync
    ...
    launch(Dispatchers.Main) { // replaces uiThread
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, that solves my problem. but can I make it shorter? I mean, create a extension function or something similar

Comment: @JoaoCarlos of course, `inline fun doAsync(block: CoroutineScope.() -> Unit) = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default, block)`

Comment: Hey @EpicPandaForce, can you give a link or some example to use this function.

Comment: `doAsync { /* do async stuff here */ }`

Answer (score 4):

coroutines library version 1.3.7:

```
GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.Default) {
            // do background work
            withContext(Main) {
                // do ui work
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

With the coroutines being out of experimental state with `Kotlin 1.3`, this is how I swapped my `Anko` code with coroutines:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    for ((index, test) in tests.withIndex()) {
        try {
            ...

            async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                OkHttpClient().newCall(test.request).execute()
                ...
            }
            ...
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {  // Dispatchers.Default
    ...
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { // Dispatchers.Main
        ...
    }
}
```

maybe for newbie, you can not log error in this coroutine. so this is the way

```
fun getErrorHandler ():CoroutineExceptionHandler {
    val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler({ coroutineContext, throwable ->
        Log.println(Log.ERROR, TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(throwable))
        throw throwable
    })

    return handler
}

GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default + getErrorHandler()) {  // Dispatchers.Default
    ...
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { // Dispatchers.Main
        ...
    }
}
```

next time, error will show in logcat. happy coroutine ^^